# How to get the length of a field collection array

Tags: 7, entities

I'm using Drupal 7 and want to get the length of the field collection array. How can I get it? Can someone provide the code snippet for that?

This is the code that prints the table.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML+RDFa 1.0//EN"
  "http://www.w3.org/MarkUp/DTD/xhtml-rdfa-1.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="<?php print $language->language; ?>" version="XHTML+RDFa 1.0" dir="<?php print $language->dir; ?>">
  <head>

    <title></title>
    <?php print $scripts; ?>
    <?php if (isset($sendtoprinter)) print $sendtoprinter; ?>
    <?php print $robots_meta; ?>
    <?php if (theme_get_setting('toggle_favicon')): ?>
      <link rel='shortcut icon' href='<?php print theme_get_setting('favicon') ?>' type='image/x-icon' />
    <?php endif; ?>
    <?php print $css; ?>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h2 style="text-align:center;font-size:10px;"><?php print"||S.S.D.||"?></h2>
    <h1 style="text-align:center;font-size:15px;"><?php print"S.K. GASES ENTERPRISES"?></h1>
    <h1 style="text-align:center;font-size:15px;"><?php print"DEALERS OF ALL TYPES OF INDUSTRIAL GASES"?></h1>
    <h1 style="text-align:center;font-size:15px;"><?php print"Distributors of Co2 Wires,Stockist and Suppliers of Lubricant Oil"?></h1>
    <h2 style="text-align:center;font-size:10px;"><?php print"Shop No. A/2/6/H- Block, MIDC, Pimpri, Pune-18, Mob.:9970107350 / 9822622134 / 8180061976"?><br>
    <?php print"<br>GST No. 27ACUFS8251K1Z8 &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; E-mail:skgases01@gmail.com"?><br>


    </h2>


    <?php if (!empty($message)): ?>
      <div class="print-message"><?php print $message; ?></div><p />
    <?php endif; ?>
    <?php if ($print_logo): ?>
      <div class="print-logo"><?php print $print_logo; ?></div>
    <?php endif; ?>



    <?php if (!isset($node->type)): ?>

      <h2 class="print-title"><?php print $print_title; ?></h2>

    <?php endif; ?>



    <table border="0px">
      <tr>
        <td colspan="2">
          <?php
          print render(field_view_field('node', $node, 'field_challan_no_', array('label'=>'inline'))); ?>
        </td>
        <td style="text-align:right;">
      <?php
         // print render(field_view_field('node', $node, 'field_date_usg', array('label'=>'inline')));
          $temp_field = field_get_items('node', $node, 'field_date_sales');
    if ($temp_field) {
            $field = check_plain($temp_field[0]['value']);
        }
        $newDate = date("d/m/Y", strtotime($temp_field[0]['value']));
    ?>
        <strong><?php print("Date:");?></strong> <?php echo $newDate;?>

        </td>
      </tr>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="2">
          <?php
          print render(field_view_field('node', $node, 'field_customer_name_ref', array('label'=>'inline'))); ?>
        </td>
        <td style="text-align:right; float:right;">
            <?php
          print render(field_view_field('node', $node, 'field_address', array('label'=>'inline'))); ?>
          </td>
      </tr>

      <tr>
        <td colspan="3">
          <strong>Filled Cylinder Details:</strong>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr><table border="1" style="border-color:black;">
       <td style="width:25%;">Cylinder No
       </td>
       <td style="width:25%;">Cylinder Type
       </td>
       <td style="width:25%;">Qty
       </td>
       <td style="width:25%;">
            Unit
       </td>
      </tr>   
       <tr>
        <td colspan="4">
        <?php 
              //$temp_field = field_get_items('node', $node, 'field_cylinder_info');
             $j=count(field_cylinder_info);
            for($i=0;$i<$j;$i++)
            {
                /*$x=$node->field_cylinder_info['und'][i]['value'];
                print $x;*/
                print render(field_view_field('node', $node, 'field_cylinder_info', array('label'=>'hidden')));
                print("<hr>");   
            }?>

          </td>


      </tr></table>

      <table>
        <tr>
          <td  colspan="3" style="text-align:center;">
              <?php print("Recieved above mentioned Cylinders in good condition complete with CAPS as per terms and conditions printed overleaf<br>");?>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </table>


      <table border="1" style="border-color:black;height:">
            <tr>
            <td colspan="6">
              <strong>Empty Cylinder Details:</strong>
            </td>
          </tr>

          <tr>
              <th style="text-align:center;color:black;">Cylinder No.</th>
              <th style="text-align:center;color:black;">Quantity</th>
              <th style="text-align:center;color:black;">Cylinder No.</th>
              <th style="text-align:center;color:black;">Quantity</th>
              <th style="text-align:center;color:black;">Cylinder No.</th>
              <th style="text-align:center;color:black;">Quantity</th>
          </tr>

          <tr>
              <td height="10"></td>
              <td height="10"></td>
              <td height="10"></td>
              <td height="10"></td>
              <td height="10"></td>
              <td height="10"></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td height="10"></td>
              <td height="10"></td>
              <td height="10"></td>
              <td height="10"></td>
              <td height="10"></td>
              <td height="10"></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td height="10"></td>
              <td height="10"></td>
              <td height="10"></td>
              <td height="10"></td>
              <td height="10"></td>
              <td height="10"></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td height="10"></td>
              <td height="10"></td>
              <td height="10"></td>
              <td height="10"></td>
              <td height="10"></td>
              <td height="10"></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
              <td height="10"></td>
              <td height="10"></td>
              <td height="10"></td>
              <td height="10"></td>
              <td height="10"></td>
              <td height="10"></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
              <td height="10"></td>
              <td height="10"></td>
              <td height="10"></td>
              <td height="10"></td>
              <td height="10"></td>
              <td height="10"></td>
          </tr>


      </table>
      <table border="0px">
      <tr>

        <td colspan="2">
          <strong><?php print("Customer's Signature:");?></strong>
        </td>
        <td style="text-align:right;">

        <strong><?php print("For S.K. GASES ENTERPRISES");?></strong> 

        </td>
      </tr>
      </table>
    </table>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can find lenght of your field collection field by this code.

```
$node = node_load(1);
$items = field_get_items('node', $node, 'field_fc');
$length  = count($items);
```

Comment: Comments have been removed. Please don't use them for extended discussion.

Comment: What we do if user need long discussion.

Comment: If the user was able to access a chat room, you could invite him there, but since the user cannot yet enter chat rooms, there isn't anything that can be done. It's important users understand that answering their question doesn't mean to follow them until they complete the task. If they have new questions, there is the _Ask Question_ button. If the answer is not clear for them, they can comment, but comments aren't thought to make extended discussions, or give continuous feedback to the OP.

Comment: If users were to ask a question, and then ask other questions in comments, Stack Exchange sites would not be much helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Another alternative for you could be,

```
$nid = '123'; //nid of the node;
$node = node_load($nid); 

$fc_field_name = 'fc_field_name'; //your fc field name
$length = count($node->{$fc_field_name}); //Your fc field name.
```

Comment: Thanks for reply..I'm now able to get the count of FC. But can not place <hr> tag between two rows. Kindly visit the link to see the image:  https://prnt.sc/kpx83b

Comment: I want to place a Horizontal line between record no. 20 and 19

Comment: That would depend on how you are printing out the returned array. Could you add your code which prints out the table as an edit to your original post.

Comment: Done. Kindly have a look.

Comment: Ok, so it seems `field_cylinder_info` is the field collection field. and you are rendering the field. In this case I would enable the `theme_debug` and see from which file the rendered portion of the table is coming from and override that particular template

Comment: To override that particular template, I need to write a custom module right?

Comment: No, you can put the template file in your {themes}/templates/*tpl.php, you don't necessarily need a module right now to override a template.

Comment: I meant you could put your template file in your `sites/all/themes/{your_theme}/templates/*tpl.php`

Answer (score 0):

Its very simple:

```
  $items = count(field_get_items('node', menu_get_object(), 'FIELD_NAME'));
  print_r($items);
```

Hope, this will help you.

Comment: Okay. Thank you..I will try this and get back to you.